# Ubuntu 19.04 encrypted full disk install partition scheme

Tags: system-installation, encryption, partitioning

Can someone explain to me the default partitioning scheme of an encrypted-full disk install of Ubuntu 19.04, or rather, the names of the partitions? During install I chose to erase, and install using the full disk, and also chose encryption. I checked the partitions after installation,and it shows this:[image: <code>lsblk</code>] It shows three partitions. Gparted shows sda1 as a EFI partition, but I'm not sure what sda2 partition is. Is it a boot partition? It looks like basically all of Ubuntu, sda3, is encrypted. I guess my main concern is, what's not encrypted?[image: gparted partition scheme]

Comment: fyi:  i booted up a netbook for comparison which had Lubuntu 19.04 installed (full disk with encryption) and it contained only the vfat[efi] & ext4[luks] partition. Lubuntu uses the `calamares` installer; but which Ubuntu 19.04 did you install with?  desktop iso? server? (and which?)

Comment: Desktop. I downloaded it yesterday from here: http://mirrors.layeronline.com/ubuntu-releases/19.04/ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: Read Nmath's answer. I'm not a gnome user so haven't installed/used the default (gnome) desktop for comparison so have no experience with what you see (otherwise i'd have upvoted the answer).  On the assumption that @Nmath is correct, the difference with my netbook is likely just a bios/uefi configuration option.

Comment: Please also read my comment with corrections to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your operating system is installed on disk `sda`.

This disk has three partitions: `sda1`, `sda2`, and `sda3`.

`sda1` and `sda2` are partitions that are needed for the system to boot up.  `sda1` is your EFI system partition (ESP).  `sda2` contains `/boot`.  The data on these partitions is not encrypted.

`sda3` is an encrypted partition.  Once you have supplied your password to unlock this partition, there are two more partitions inside: your root (`/`) partition and also a swap partition.  All of the contents of `sda3` are encrypted.

Comment: `sda1` is the ESP; `sda2` is `/boot`. There's no MBR in a GPT drive. Yes, `sda3` is the encrypted part but likely contain only the root partition because the default for 19.04 is to use swapfile, not a swap partition.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia you're correct about `sda2` being the `/boot` partition.  I'll edit the answer.  In this case, however, per OP's screenshot, `sda3` contains a 117GB root partition and also a 976MB swap partition.